# Mysql error 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'

Tags: php, xenforo

So: I just bought an VPS and installed Ubuntu on it. After I installed Ubuntu I installed MySQL and created a database.

Now: I want to connect XenForo to the mysql database but I'm getting the error 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'

Could anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Actively refused means, the host actually received your connection request, but denied it.

Things to check/verify:

- Does the Service listen to TCP (not UDP) on the port used, usually 3306?
- Is a firewall or proxy between your script and the database?
- Is your MySQL server accepting connections from "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" (compare with connection parameters in your script)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ye I did this:   

sudo ufw allow out 3306/tcp  

and

sudo ufw allow in 3306/tcp